Swipe Left in a listview within a tab controller
I have a listview in a maui contentpage.  That content page is within a tabbedpage.  I have some text and an image in a cell in the listview.  I would like to swipe left on a cell and be able to delete.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work.  when I swipe left in android (device and simulator), nothing happens.  I also tried to use a collectionview, but got the same result.  My xaml for my page is below.  I assume that this is something I am going wrong.  I feel like another set of eyes would be helpful.  Does anyone see anything that I should look at?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BWD.Pages.ImageList"
             Title="ImageList">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add from camera"
                x:Name="CameraAdd"
                IconImageSource="camera.png"
                Clicked="CameraAdd_Clicked"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add from photo library"
                x:Name="PhotoLibraryAdd"
                IconImageSource="imagelist.png" 
                Clicked="PhotoLibraryAdd_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
<ListView x:Name="PicList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <SwipeView>
                        <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                            <SwipeItems>
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete" 
                                        Invoked="SwipeItem_Invoked">
                                </SwipeItem>
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding PicFileUrl}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding PicTagList}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </SwipeView>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>


Can you possibly create a GitHub repro for this so i can take a look?

Did it work when you swiped left and clicked the delete button? Can you show the code behind and I would like to test.
